# How to view image details (Exif data) for any photo?

Tags: photos, exif

I know how to view Exif data (shutter speed, ISO, exposure, time taken, etc.) for photos taken with the Nokia/Lumia Camera app (open the app, expand app bar, tap "picture info"), but what about photos taken with other apps? Or indeed, other devices/cameras? For instance, I often transfer photos from my 808 PureView to my Lumia 920, for editing and sharing. But there doesn't seem to be any way to view their details like I can on a Windows PC.

Have I missed something? I'm running WP 8.1 Update 1, in case it matters.

Comment: Are you wanting to view the info on the device you took the picture with, or a separate one? If you want to view it on the device you took the picture with, Picture Info by Spaso Lazarevic or Photo-Info by Benjamin Sautermeister should do the trick. If you want to view details on a picture taken from another device, I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: @Drowin Both. I want to view image data on my Lumia 920. The photos, as I explained, may have been taken on my Lumia with a variety of camera apps, or on a separate device altogether (e.g. my 808 PV).

Comment: It depends on whether or not your camera app saves the exif data. Also, how are you transferring the photos?

Comment: @Drowin Bluetooth, download from OneDrive, copy over USB from a PC... It shouldn't really matter. Point is, I have photos on my Lumia that weren't taken with that phone and with the Lumia Camera app. And yes, let's assume the photos have Exif data. Any way to view that data without a third-party app?

Comment: USB transfer should work with the app I mentioned (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/photo-info/ac39aa30-c9b1-4dc6-af2d-1cc17d9807cc). But no, there is no way in the OS.

Comment: @Drowin Thanks. You may want to post your app suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [Picture Info](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=04e3caac-2a94-4488-9e8a-86c856aa637f) by Spaso Lazarevic or [Photo-Info](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=ac39aa30-c9b1-4dc6-af2d-1cc17d9807cc) by Benjamin Sautermeister should give you the information you want, but there's no way built into the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the Exif data in your phone, you'll need an app for that:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=exif

If you want to see the exif data on your PC, you can see some of it through right-click -> properties. Additional tags can be made visible through tools like IrfanView http://www.irfanview.com/